# I'm having trouble with limitkeypress.js and IE10

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer

In a project I'm working on, I have a textbox where the user has to input his name. To avoid the user from entering numbers I used the    [jquery.limitkeypress.js](http://brianjaeger.com/docs/limitkeypress/jquery.limitkeypress.js) library written by [Brian Jaeger](http://brianjaeger.com/) and every thing was working perfectly until I tested the website in Internet Explorer 10. In IE10, you can input all the letters you want, and you can not input number or weird symbols just as I wanted but when I type a space and then a letter, I see the letter print right to the space and then the space disappearing and the latter shifting to the left. The weird thing is that if I wait like 30 seconds after typing the space to type the letter it works fine.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

jquery.limitkeypress.js has some issue with ie, I recommend you to use a more powerful library.

http://github.com/RobinHerbots/jquery.inputmask

With this library you can use something like this:

```
$(".numbers").inputmask('Regex', {
    mask: "9",
    repeat: 11,
    placeholder: ""
});
```

It works perfectly on ie. :)

Answer (score 1):

Sorry i have not updated that plugin in a few years but...

[jquery.limitkeypress](http://brianjaeger.com/process.php) now works with IE9+ there was an issue with how the selection was determined.

IE11 killed support for their document.selection but they kept the document.setSelectionRange which i was using to test what browser was being used...

IE9 enabled document.selectionStart and document.selectionEnd so i now check directly what browser version of IE peoples are using...

I added this to check for IE version:

```
var ie = (function(){
var undef,
  v = 3,
  div = document.createElement('div'),
  all = div.getElementsByTagName('i');
while (
  div.innerHTML = '<!--[if gt IE ' + (++v) + ']><i></i><![endif]-->',
  all[0]
);
return v > 4 ? v : undef;
}());
```

So my selection functions now look like this:

```
function getSelectionStart(o) {
  if (ie < 9) {
    var r = document.selection.createRange().duplicate()
    r.moveEnd('character', o.value.length)
    if (r.text == '') return o.value.length
      return o.value.lastIndexOf(r.text)
    } else return o.selectionStart
  }
function getSelectionEnd(o) {
  if (ie < 9) {
    var r = document.selection.createRange().duplicate()
    r.moveStart('character', -o.value.length)
    return r.text.length
  } else return o.selectionEnd
}
```